# Deletando imagem local do produto Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Bom tenho um produto e tenho uma imagem sendo gravada localmente.

Preciso que no *backend* quando o produto for deletado a imagem local seja deletada.

Quando faço o delete apaga os dados do banco apaga as informações da imagem no banco, porém não apaga a imagem local.

Qual seria o melhor jeito de fazer?

A minha rota :

```
Route::get('/{id}/destroy',['as'=>'products.destroy', 'uses'=>'AdminProductsController@destroy']);
```

A minha função para deletar o produto:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->productModel->find($id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('products');
}
```

Função para remover imagem na view de imagens

```
 public function destroyImage(ProductImage $productImage, $id)
{
    $image = $productImage->find($id);

    if(file_exists(public_path() .'/uploads/'.$image->id.'.'.$image->extension)) {

        Storage::disk('public_local')->delete($image->id . '.' . $image->extension);
    }

    $product = $image->product;
    $image->delete();


    return redirect()->route('products.images', ['id'=>$product->id]);

}
```

Comment: A imagem local seria na maquina no cliente?

Comment: No servidor local

Answer (score 1):

Ao deletar o produto, seu método `destroy` precisa também deletar o arquivo criado.

Você pode fazer isso diretamente no método:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $disk = Storage::disk('local');

    $this->productModel->find($id);
    $disk->delete($this->productModel->filePath);

    $this->productModel->delete();

    return redirect()->route('products');
}
```

Uma forma mais elegante seria usar o [*event* `deleting()` do Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events):

No método `boot()` do seu `app\Providers\AppProvider.php` insira:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Namespace\Para\Product::deleting(function ($product) {
         Storage::disk('local')->delete($product->filePath);

         return true;
    });
}
```

**PS.: Estou assumindo que você está armazenando o nome do arquivo no banco (`$product->filePath`)**

Comment: ErrorException in Local.php line 200:
unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\public\uploads\): Permission denied , procurei mas n consegui resolver esse erro de permissão... alguma dica?

Comment: Já definiu as permissões na pasta?

Comment: dei permissão de tudo para 'todos'

Comment: Como fica um `dd($product->filePath)` ? Aparece o caminho completo para o arquivo?

Comment: retornou null.. editei o post e postei o meu destroy da imagem... dessa forma deletando somente a imagem deleta na pasta..

Comment: @raphael estou assumindo que você está armazenando o nome do arquivo no banco ($product->filePath). Você precisa alterar essa linha para o campo no seu banco que armazena o nome do arquivo

Comment: @raphael conseguiu ?

Comment: tinha dado um tempo nesse projeto pois estou focado em outro.. mas depois volto pra dizer se ja resolvi.. vlw pela ajuda